# Changing a `SKSpriteNode.texture` without a flicker

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, swift2

I have a `SKSpriteNode` that needs to change the `texture`, since in my 2d isomorphic game it needs to use different frames when the object is facing different directions. At first I accomplished this quite simply: `self.sprite.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: frameName)`, but I found that this caused a "flicker" where the sprite turned invisible for a moment (presumably while loading up the new texture).

I decided to implement a static cache of `SKTexture` objects to avoid re-loading from disk. It works well, but it still suffers from the same flicker problem **only the first time each frame is used**. Check out [this video](http://inzania.com/temp/jittery.mov) to see what I mean. Source code:

```
class GameObject : GameSprite {
  static var textureCache:[String:SKTexture] = [:]

  func setup() {
    self.sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: assetName)
    for dir in Direction.directions {
      let textureName = self.assetPrefix + dir.description.lowercaseString
      GameObject.textureCache[textureName] = SKTexture(imageNamed: textureName)
    }
  }

  var assetName:String {
    return self.assetPrefix + self.direction.description.lowercaseString
  }

  var direction:Direction {
    set {
      if self.dir != newValue.rawValue {
        self.dir = newValue.rawValue
        self.sprite.texture = GameObject.textureCache[assetName]
      }
    }
    get { return Direction(rawValue: self.dir)! }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: If it is possible try reducing your image size.

Comment: Try preloading the textures with https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKTexture/preloadWithCompletionHandler: